# How to change custom sound in UILocalNotification in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I am using custom sound in uilocalnotification in ios. 
but its not play.
file is exist in Document folder.
notification is working with `local.soundName= UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;`

```
        NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/DingDongTone.wav",documentsPath];
        local.soundName=path;
```

Please help.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please re-read what apple says -

> For this property, specify the filename (including extension) of a
>   sound resource in the application’s main bundle or
>   [`UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW16) to request the default system
>   sound. When the system displays an alert for a local notification or
>   badges an application icon, it plays this sound. The default value is
>   `nil` (no sound). Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not
>   supported.  If you specify a file with a sound that plays over 30
>   seconds, the default sound is played instead.

according to this `filename` is the `path` of file in resources of `main bundle` not in the `document directory`

> Note : also the file shouldn't be longer then `30 sec.`

Comment: Thanks for info. can i play .caf sound in background when i receive localnotification. but sound file is in document folder.

Answer (score 1):

`@saadnib` said i completely agree with him for to  `specify the filename` (including extension) of a `sound resource should in the application’s main bundle`

So copy your sound in application’s main bundle then don't `forget to copy` your `path string` like this and it should work.

```
  yourLocalNotification.soundName= [yourSoundFilePath copy];
```